# Hibernate many to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Im trying to map my database tables, so that I can have *many to many* relationship between Books and Author tables.

First, it was *one to many* relationship design, by thanks to @xenteros and @Amer Qarabsa i started to redesigning it into many to many relationship.

So, this is how my **database schema** looks like:
[image]

**Author** (model) class:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    private Set<Book> authorsBooks = new HashSet<Book>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Set<Book> getAuthorsBooks() {
        return authorsBooks;
    }

    public void setAuthorsBooks(Set<Book> authorsBooks) {
        this.authorsBooks = authorsBooks;
    }
}
```

**Book** (model) class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private int bookId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "title_original")
    private String titleOriginal;
    @Column(name = "premiere_date")
    private Date premiereDate;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") })
    private Set<Author> booksAuthors = new HashSet<Author>(0);


    public int getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }
    public void setBookId(int bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitleOriginal() {
        return titleOriginal;
    }
    public void setTitleOriginal(String titleOriginal) {
        this.titleOriginal = titleOriginal;
    }


    public Date getPremiereDate() {
        return premiereDate;
    }
    public void setPremiereDate(Date premiereDate) {
        this.premiereDate = premiereDate;
    }


    public Set<Author> getBookAuthors() {
        return this.booksAuthors;
    }
    public void setBookAuthors(Set<Author> bookAuthors) {
        this.booksAuthors = bookAuthors;
    }


}
```

**AuthorController** class:

```
@Controller
public class AuthorController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Author>> getAuthors() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authorRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Author> getAuthor(@PathVariable int id) {
        Author author = authorRepository.findOne(id);

        if (author != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(authorRepository.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addAuthor(@RequestBody Author author) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authorRepository.save(author), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAuthor(@PathVariable int id) {
        authorRepository.delete(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /*
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/authors"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allAuthors() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("authors/home"); //viewname przekazujemy z folderu templates
        List<Author> author = authorService.getAllAuthors();
        modelAndView.addObject("authors",author);  //ta nazwa tutaj "authors" sluzy potem do wykorzystania jej w templacie
        return modelAndView;
    }
    */

}
```

**BookController** class:

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Book>> getBooks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBook(@PathVariable int id) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findOne(id);

        if (book != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.save(book), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteBook(@PathVariable int id) {
        bookRepository.delete(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /*
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/books"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allBooks() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("books/home"); //viewname przekazujemy z folderu templates
        List<Book> book = bookService.getAllBooks();
        modelAndView.addObject("books",book);  //ta nazwa tutaj "books" sluzy potem do wykorzystania jej w templacie
        return modelAndView;
    }
    */


}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-07 13:02:18.638 ERROR 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'bookController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> eu.fitk.controller.BookController.addBook(eu.fitk.model.Book)
to {[],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'authorController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> eu.fitk.controller.AuthorController.addAuthor(eu.fitk.model.Author) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at eu.fitk.BookwebApplication.main(BookwebApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'bookController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> eu.fitk.controller.BookController.addBook(eu.fitk.model.Book)
to {[],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'authorController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> eu.fitk.controller.AuthorController.addAuthor(eu.fitk.model.Author) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:576) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:540) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:264) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:250) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:214) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:127) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of your join table should not be the same as one of your tables
change to book_author for example

```
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") })
```

Comment: so, should I create additional table book_author with two primary keys book_id and author_id which are also foreign keys of authors and books tables?

Comment: didn't know I can do that, interesting feature! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You must have `getId()` method or a field annotated with `@Id`. Move your annotations to fields and everything will work fine.

Also, your relation isn't `@OneToMany`. Can't author be an author of many books? It's `@ManyToMany`.

Your problem is also, that you have two tables, that are called in the same way. Change the name of your join table to `book-author` or similar.

Comment: btw, are you suggesting creating additional table for that many to many relationship?

Comment: @TylerDurden hibernate should do that for you

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.save(book), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/addauthor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addAuthor(@RequestBody Author author) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authorRepository.save(author), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

methods had the same default "value" and it was impossible for Hibernate to determine which one to chose from them when entering "/" adress. Solution was just adding different mapping values:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addauthor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addAuthor(@RequestBody Author author) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authorRepository.save(author), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/addbook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.save(book), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```